Moving ShellContent objects to another XAML page
I would like to move the Cats and Dogs ShellContent objects, as seen in the following classic example, to another (Domestic) XAML Page while keeping the navigation layout as is (two tabs to the top).
<Shell xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Xaminals.Views"
   x:Class="Xaminals.AppShell">
 <TabBar>
   <Tab Title="Domestic" Icon="paw.png">
       <ShellContent Title="Cats"
                     ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CatsPage}" />
       <ShellContent Title="Dogs"
                     ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DogsPage}" />
   </Tab>
   <Tab Title="Monkeys" Icon="monkey.png">
       <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MonkeysPage}" />
   </Tab>
 </TabBar>
</Shell>

Here is what I have tried so far, but first, I'm not sure if this is the best practice to accomplish this goal, and second, for some reason the Cats and Dogs tabs turned into items under a left side minimized menu page.
<Shell xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   x:Class="Xaminals.Views.DomesticPage">
  <ShellContent Title="Cats"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CatsPage}" />
  <ShellContent Title="Dogs"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DogsPage}" />
</Shell>

Refer to the DomesticPage in AppShell:
<TabBar>
  <Tab Title="Domestic" Icon="paw.png">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DomesticPage}" />
  </Tab>
  <Tab Title="Monkeys" Icon="monkey.png">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MonkeysPage}" />
  </Tab>
</TabBar>


I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you elaborate on what you want to achieve?

Stop doing what you are doing. Content stays in the Tab (shell section), Tab stays in TabBar (Shell item) and TabBar (together with other items) stays in the Shell. That is the hierarchy. You cannot take a Tab (the tab is the bottom thingy, not the top ones) and declare it as Shell. If you say why you are doing this, someone may suggest alternative solutions.

@JessieZhang-MSFT I'm trying to accomplish something similar to the Partial View concept in ASP.NET Core by moving the Shell Contents of the first Tab into a partial XAML file.

@H.A.H. I'm trying to free the AppShell page from clutter by allowing only one Page per Tab. Moving the contents of the first Tab into a sub XAML file, would help me accomplish this goal.

moving the Shell Contents of the first Tab into a partial XAML file Hi @usefulBee, what's the special partial XAML file? Can you share a specific design you want to achieve?

Based on your code, I did a test. The result is that if we put a shell inside of a shell, we cannot see the content of page  CatsPage and DogsPage on tab Domestic.

@JessieZhang-MSFT, I put this temporarily aside for now. But to answer your question, which I appreciate, the first) reason to have a partial view is to make the AppShell look cleaner and free of clutter, as seen in the last code example; this way it includes only the main pages vs what I consider as sub pages. Secondly) as I started developing the settings page, I currently use reflection to get a list of all pages in the pages folder; therefore, I prefer one of the main pages returned to be DomesticPage. I'm thinking now about getting the names of Tabs instead.

Thanks for your feedback. And waiting for your good news. :)

@JessieZhang-MSFT, just added a solution. Would like to hear your feedback.

This is really the closest idea I have found so far in Maui to the concept of PartialViews. Instead of using a standard template of ContentPage or ContentView suggested by Visual Studio, you manipulate any of those templates to represent a stand-alone visual element; for example, VerticalSatckLayout, Grid, etc...
In This Maui sample, the author calls those sub XAML files, Widgets.
According to MS documentation:

.NET MAUI views are the UI objects such as labels, buttons, and sliders that are commonly known as controls or widgets in other environments.

Based on this idea, in order to move ShellContent objects (Cats and Dogs per example) to another XAML file (Domestic), I created a XAML page that contains the Tab element only, and in the code behind file inherit from the Tab Control/Class. As follows:
Domestic Page
<Tab xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   x:Class="Xaminals.Views.DomesticPageTab">
  <ShellContent Title="Cats"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CatsPage}" />
  <ShellContent Title="Dogs"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DogsPage}" />
</Tab>

Code Behind
public partial class DomesticPageTab: Tab
{
  public DomesticPageTab()
   {
     InitializeComponent();
   }
}

The ShellApp page should look something like this
<TabBar>
  <views:DomesticPageTab Title="Domestic" Icon="paw.png" />

  <Tab Title="Monkeys" Icon="monkey.png">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MonkeysPage}" />
  </Tab>
</TabBar>

So far, this solution works seamlessly, presentation and navigation wise, and the associated ViewModels are initiating correctly as well. I'm not saying moving those objects in a separate XAML file is necessary. But I think the idea of stand-alone widgets might prove helpful in other scenarios.
